# Using Java Executor on AppEngine causes AccessControlException

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

How do you get java.util.concurrent.Executor or CompletionService to work on Google AppEngine?  The classes are all [officially white-listed](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html), but I get a runtime security error when trying to submit asynchronous tasks.

Code:

```
    // uses the async API but this factory makes it so that tasks really
    // happen sequentially
    Executor executor = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    // wrap Executor in CompletionService
    CompletionService<String> completionService = 
        new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executor);
    final SomeTask someTask = new SomeTask();
    // this line throws exception
    completionService.submit(new Callable<String>(){
        public String call() {
            return someTask.doNothing("blah");
        }
    });
    // alternately, send Runnable task directly to Executor,
    // which also throws an exception
    executor.execute(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            someTask.doNothing("blah");
        }
    });
}

private class SomeTask{
    public String doNothing(String message){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Exception:

> java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission
>   modifyThreadGroup)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:288)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:332)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.(Thread.java:565)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:542)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addThread(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:672)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderCorePoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:697)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:652)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.submit(ExecutorCompletionService.java:152)

This code works fine when run on Tomcat or via command-line JVM.  However, it chokes in the AppEngine SDK Jetty container (tried with Eclipse plugin and the maven-gae-plugin).

AppEngine is likely designed to not allow potentially dangerous programs to run, so I could see them completely disabling thread creation.  However, why would Google allow you to create a class, but not allow you to call methods on it?  White-listing java.util.concurrent is misleading.

Is there some other way to do parallel/simultaneous/concurrent tasks on GAE?

Answer (score 11):

The [App Engine Java Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html) states

> an app cannot spawn threads

This is even more clearly stated in their docs on [The Java Servlet Environment](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html)

> **Threads**
>
> A Java application cannot create a new `java.lang.ThreadGroup` nor a new `java.lang.Thread`. These restrictions also apply to JRE classes that make use of threads. For example, an application cannot create a new `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`, or a `java.util.Timer`. An application can perform operations against the current thread, such as `Thread.currentThread().dumpStack()`.

Perhaps the white-listing is so that you can work with libraries that accept `Executors`, and you can supply your own `Executor` that performs the work in the current thread.

You could try the experimental [Task Queues](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that answers my question.

Comment: This is no longer true. You can now create threads in a constrained way. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#threads

Answer (score 1):

You can start thread in the request context

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#Java_The_sandbox